# Populate database table on a frequent basis using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa

One of my Java application's functionality is to read and parse very frequently (almost every 5 minutes) an xml file and populate a database table. I have created a cron job to do that. Most of the columns' values remain the same but for certain columns there may be a frequent update on the value. I was wondering what is the most efficient way of doing that:
1) Delete the table every time and re-create it or
2) Update the table data and specifically the column where a change in the source file has appeared. 
The number of rows parsed and persisted every time is about 40000-50000.
I would assume that around 2000-3000 rows need to update on every cron job run.
I am using JPA to persist data to a mysql server  and I have gone for the first option so far.
Obviously for both options the job would execute as a single transaction.

Any ideas which one is better and possibly any optimization suggestions?

Comment: Does each entry in the XML have a unique identifier or business key that could be used to match it up with the database row?

Comment: yes it has a unique id

Comment: My advice would be to implement the two or three solutions you have in mind, and measure to see wich one is the fastest, if you really want this to be fast. If you just wnat it to be fast enough, then implement one, and measure if it's fast enough. Be careful about the size of the first-level cache if you read many rows during the transaction. You might need to read and update batches of rows, and then clear the persistence context before the next batch.

Comment: @JB Nizet The size you mentioned is a good point. Just found that persisting all rows in one go takes long time so I am going to break it into smaller batch runs and flush every run

Comment: Have you considered a non-java option? Like maybe Load XML: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-xml.html

Comment: I am afraid this is not an option because of the complexity of xml files and parsers

Comment: @Dimitris How do you know whether a value needs to be updated? Can you detect it using the XML file only or would you need to query the database?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest scheduling your jobs using something more sophisticated than cron. For instance, [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

Comment: You can't judge a book by its cover.